# The edit control in Microsoft Edge is auto capitalizing the letter i

Tags: support, editor

I'm typing this question in Edge.  Let's say I want to express this as a line of code in a question or answer

```
int i = 42;
```

When I actually type into the edit window, the lone letter `i` in that statement gets auto-corrected to capital `I`.  Hence, this is what I just had to correct to make the statement above work.

```
int I = 42;
```

This didn't always use to be the case. I'm not sure if Edge introduced this bug, or if there is an HTML style missing that would turn off auto-correct.  Doesn't repro on Chrome.

Update: If I use the F12 tools to hack in a `spellcheck=false` attribute into the `<textarea>` control, then the issue goes away.  My CSS debugging skills start to get more limited after that. I'm not sure if spellcheck is on by default on Edge different from Chrome, or if Edge's behavior will auto-correct a lone letter `i` (damnit - it did it again!) whereas chrome's autocorrect won't.

Comment: Almost certainly an Edge change, not a Stack Overflow one. UWP apps now have built-in autocorrect. The frustration is no longer just in the palm of your hand.

Comment: @CodyGray - The fact of the matter is that the `<textarea>` control is missing the `spellcheck=false` attribute.

Comment: If it changed that, the poor spelling we encounter here would get even worse. If it doesn't repro on Chrome, I imagine it will go away once Microsoft's browser becomes based on Blink.

Comment: AFAIK, Chrome does spellcheck (which is certainly preferable) but never autocorrects (which should be the correct behavior for Edge).

Comment: @RobertLongson Windows' autocorrect only works in specific apps (usually Microsoft-made UWP as well as Office and some MS classic apps). It doesn't really matter what Edge is based on. The stable version will likely always have autocorrect.

Comment: @TheWanderer of course it matters if Edge changes to Blink. Edge will then do whatever Blink does.

Comment: @RobertLongson you missed my point. This isn't related to the browser engine, it's related to Windows autocorrect, which only works in programs that Microsoft selects. If MS decided it should be enabled in Chrome, then Chrome would have the same problem as Edge.

Comment: So... I think what's being said is, this is an ... Edge case!

Comment: you could install [tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) and disable spell check globally.

Comment: I Don't have the repro on `I` but "don't" get capitilised. But autocorrects only happends in comment tho. For exemple adding double quote arround those words trigger capitalisation.